# Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined Nodejs and React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a service in Nodejs which code looks like the following:

```
app.get('/getbackgroundPQI/:layer/:county/:year', (req, res) => {

const { layer, county,year } = req.params;
const sqc = sqlConn;
console.log(layer,county,year)
const layers = {
    MaintenanceTypes: "GetMaintnenanceTypeBkgLayer",
    LoadRestrictions: "GetLoadRestrictionBkgLayer",
    Ownership: "GetOwnershipBkgLayer",
    TotalSurfaceDepth: "GetTotalSurfaceDepth",
    SurfaceAge: "GetSurfaceAgeBkgLayer",
    SurfaceAgeBitu: "GetSurfaceAgeBkgLayerBit",
    SurfaceAgeConc: "GetSurfaceAgeBkgLayerConc",
    PublicImpact: "GetCurrentYearConsPublicImpact",
    PlannedImprovement: "GetPlannedImprovements",
    StructureCondition: "GetStructureConditions",
    StructureMaterial: "GetStructureMaterials",
    SurfaceType: "GetSurfaceTypeBkgLayer",
    SpecialConstructionHistory: "GetSpecialConstructionHistory",
    Age: "GetPerformanceAge",
    getPQI: "GetPerformancePQI",
    DropAge: "GetDropdownAge",
    DropPQI: "GetDropdownPQI"

};

const query = `
    EXEC ${layers[layer]} @county @year;
`;

const params = [sqc.paramize('county', 'year', county, year, sql.Int)];

sqc.SqlSelectParamCall(
    query, params, (data) => {
       // console.log("MY Data"+data);
        //convert data
        res.send(data);
    }, true);
});
```

My react Calling of the service looks like the following:

```
 selectBackgroundLayerPQI = (layer, e) => {
    const county = AgencyInfo.getSelectedAgencyId();
    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    console.log(year);
    if (layer === 'none')
    {
        this.props.clickFunctions.onLoadBackgroundLayer([]);
        this.props.clickFunctions.toggleSpecialLayer(false);
        this.legendName = '';
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: `${config.server}\\getbackgroundPQI\\${layer}\\${county}\\${year}`,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.props.clickFunctions.toggleSpecialLayer(false);
                this.setState({ backgroundLegend: data[1], legendName: data[2][0].LegendName});
                this.props.clickFunctions.onLoadBackgroundLayer(data[0]);
            },
        });
    }

    this.setState({ backgroundLayer: layer });
}
```

Now if I try to hit the url of the service from browser as http://localhost:3001/getbackgroundPQI/getPQI/77/2019 my nodejs server shows the parameters which are read using req.params but however I have an error which is following:

```
getPQI 77 2019
info: Sql connection started...
error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
at Request.validateParameters (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:154:36)
at Request.transformIntoExecuteSqlRpc (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:87:16)
at Connection.execSql (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:717:15)
at C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:1062:77
at Pool.dispense [as _dispense] (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:310:12)
at Pool.acquire (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:436:8)
at Request._acquire (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1185:37)
at Request.TediousRequest.query (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:773:21)
at Request._query (C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1580:54)
at C:\Users\DOTSC_souroy\Desktop\PrfCat\Geographic-Roadway-Inventory-Tool-JS\grit-server\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1540:24
```

I have mentioned both my nodejs and reactjs code just to let you know what I am doing. The reactjs function is called from a Button in frontend. I have a storedprocedure which if I execute in the database works fine and it returns me the result. 
I will be grateful if anyone can help me with the problem.

Comment: Try placing assignment to `const query` in one line instead of breaking it into 3 lines. I have experienced issues with back ticks using this way.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks but it is solved. The error was on the way service was created.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the nodejs code to the following:

```
app.get('/getbackgroundPQI/:county/:year', (req, res) => {

const { county,year } = req.params;
const sqc = sqlConn;
let query = 'EXEC dbo.TestGetPerformancePQI '+county+','+year;
let params = [
    sqc.paramize('county',county,sql.Int()),
    sqc.paramize('year',year,sql.Int()),

];

sqc.SqlExecuteStatementCallback(
    query, params,null,(data) => {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

And I changed the React service calling as the following:

```
 selectBackgroundLayerPQI = (layer, e) => {
    const county = AgencyInfo.getSelectedAgencyId();
    const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    console.log(year);
    if (layer === 'none')
    {
        this.props.clickFunctions.onLoadBackgroundLayer([]);
        this.props.clickFunctions.toggleSpecialLayer(false);
        this.legendName = '';
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: `${config.server}\\getbackgroundPQI\\${county}\\${year}`,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.props.clickFunctions.toggleSpecialLayer(false);
                this.setState({ backgroundLegend: data[1], legendName: data[2][0].LegendName});
                this.props.clickFunctions.onLoadBackgroundLayer(data[0]);
            },
        });
    }

    this.setState({ backgroundLayer: layer });
}
```